# can anyone help me with my spell check code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is what i have, comments describe what im trying to do

There are words put in a text file where some words are spelt wrong and test text files aswell which are to be used to spell check.

e.g. >>> spellCheck("test1.txt")
    {'exercsie': 1, 'finised': 1}

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
def spellCheck(textFileName):

    # Use the open method to open the words file.
    # Read the list of words into a list named wordsList
    # Close the file

    file=open("words.txt","r")
    wordsList = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    # Open the file whos name was provided as the textFileName variable
    # Read the text from the file into a list called wordsToCheck
    # Close the file

    file=open(textFileName, "r")
    wordsToCheck = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    for i in range(0,len(wordsList)): wordsList[i]=wordsList[i].replace("\n","")
    for i in range(0,len(wordsToCheck)): wordsToCheck[i]=wordsToCheck[i].replace("\n","")


    # The next line creates the dictionary
    # This dictionary will have the word that has been spelt wrong as the key and the number of times it has been spelt wrong as the value
    spellingErrors = dict(wordsList)


    # Loop through the wordsToCheck list
    # Change the current word into lower case
    # If the current word does not exist in the wordsList then
            # Check if the word already exists in the spellingErrors dictionary
                    # If it does not exist than add it to the dictionary with the initial value of 1.
                    # If it does exist in the dictionary then increase the value by 1

    # Return the dictionary
    char_low = ascii_lowercase
    char_up = ascii_uppercase
    for char in wordsToCheck[0]:
       if char in wordsToCheck[0] in char_up:
            result.append(char_low)
    for i in wordsToCheck[0]:
       if wordsToCheck[0] not in wordsList:
            if wordsToCheck[0] in dict(wordsList):
                    dict(wordsList) + 1
            elif wordsToCheck[0] not in dict(wordsList):
                    dict(wordsList) + wordsToCheck[0]
                    dict(wordsList) + 1
    return dict(wordsList)
```

my code returns an an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    spellCheck("test1.txt")
  File "J:\python\SpellCheck(1).py", line 36, in spellCheck
    spellingErrors = dict(wordsList)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required

So can anyone help me?

Comment: Seriously? Returning an empty dict? Also, dict() + 1 raises TypeError

Comment: Of course it returns an empty dict: that's what `dict()` is!

Comment: Your question has less to do with how to implement a spell checker, and more to do with basic Python. Maybe amend your question to clarify what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 8):

I applied [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and rewrote unpythonic code.

```
import collections

def spell_check(text_file_name):
    # dictionary for word counting
    spelling_errors = collections.defaultdict(int)

    # put all possible words in a set
    with open("words.txt") as words_file:
        word_pool = {word.strip().lower() for word in words_file}

    # check words
    with open(text_file_name) as text_file:
        for word in (word.strip().lower() for word in text_file):
            if not word in word_pool:
                spelling_errors[word] += 1

    return spelling_errors
```

You might want to read about the [with statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Your code with the `ascii_uppercase` and `ascii_lowercase` screams: [Read the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) and learn the basics. That code is a collection of "I don't know what I'm doing but I do it anyway.".

**Some more explanations concerning your old code**:

You use

```
char_low = ascii_lowercase
```

There is no need for `char_low` because you never manipulate that value. Just use the original `ascii_lowercase`. Then there is the following part of your code:

```
for char in wordsToCheck[0]:
    if char in wordsToCheck[0] in char_up:
        result.append(char_low)
```

I'm not quite sure what you try to do here. It seems that you want to convert the words in the list to lower case. In fact, if that code would run - which it doesn't - you would append the whole lower case alphabet to `result`for every upper case character of the word in the list. Nevertheless you don't use `result`in the later code, so no harm is done. It would be easy to add a `print wordsToCheck[0]` before the loop or a `print char` in the loop to see what happens there.

The last part of the code is just a mess. You access just the first word in each list - maybe because you don't know what that list looks like. That is coding by *trial and error*. Try coding by *knowledge* instead.

You don't really know what a `dict` does and how to use it. I could explain it here but there is this wonderful tutorial at www.python.org that you might want to read first, especially [the chapter dealing with dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). If you study those explanations and still don't understand it feel free to come back with a new question concerning this.

I used a `defaultdict` instead of a standard dictionary because it makes life easier here. If you define `spelling errors` as `dict` instead a part of my code would have to change to

```
if not word in word_pool:
    if not word in spelling_errors:
        spelling_errors[word] = 1
    else:
        spelling_errors[word] += 1
```

BTW, the code I wrote runs for me without any problems. I get a dictionary with the missing words (lower case) as keys and a count of that word as the corresponding value.

Comment: your code doesnt return what i was looking for its supposed to return the words that are spelled wrong

Comment: You're right. I accidently used the string `'word'` instead of the variable `word`. I fixed it.

Comment: can you edit my code to get the correct output please? id like to see where i went wrong im very new to python and coding

Comment: Some things to think about: Why do you think you need `char_low` and `char_up`? What is the content of `wordsToCheck[0]`? What is dict(wordsList)? What do you think happens in the line with `dict(wordsList) + 1`? Don't guess, use `print`and look what really happens. (It's past midnight over here in Europe now. Going to bed.)

Comment: i have char_low and char_up to change the letter of a word to lowercase and with wordstocheck[0] i was hoping that this would apply to the first index in the wordstocheck list. dict(wordslist) im not really sure of either im not sure how to implement the dict function and i was just trying things out and i cant use print to see what the end parts of my code do because i get an error as i dont know how to implement the dict function

Comment: I added some explanations. If you think that the answer might have been helpful feel free to accept it.

Comment: @Matthias +1 since you probably won't get the accept.